# how to access arry of objects in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this result from `var_dump($_REQUEST);`

```
array(1) { ["email"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "email1@example.com" [1]=> string(15) "email2@example.com" } }
```

How to iterate through the arry so that I can get like this result:

```
$email[0]=email1@example.com
$email[1]=email2@example.com
```

**Update:** Edited the indexes

**Update2:**

I used:

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
var_dump($email);
```

but now I am getting:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "email1@example.com" [1]=> string(18) "email2@example.com" }
```

Comment: `$email = $_REQUEST['email']` will do what you want.

Comment: But the indexes are 0 and 1, not 1 and 2. Array indexes start at 0.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you dear Barmar, but it shows blank result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_REQUEST['email']` is the array you want to iterate through.

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['email'] as $i => $email) {
    $num = $i + 1;
    echo "\$email[$num]=$email<br>";
}
```

Comment: Please Barmar....how to put each email in variable? like `$e[$num]=$email[$num]` I want to prepare variable before inserting data inside database

Comment: `$e[$num] = $email;`

Comment: It seems like you need to brush up on PHP basics regarding variables and arrays.

Comment: Yes indeed Barmar...I am very biggener